# How to access metadata from feature in a geodatabase with ogrinfo from command line?

Tags: gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

Before loading a feature class from a File Geodatabase (.gdb) to PostgreSQL, I would like to check some general information such as the number of polygons, the bounding box or the attribute table.

The following GDAL versions is installed on my computer: GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23

Is there a way to do this in the command line? I would try it with ogrinfo, but did not find information about that in the internet, but some hints on this [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet) only provided information for ESRI Shapefiles (.shp)

Comment: A **Personal** Geodatabase uses a  `.mdb` suffix.  **File** Geodatabase uses a `.gdb` suffix.

Comment: You are right. Changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, if your version of GDAL is built to support Personal Geodatabases, you should be able to retrieve metadata using `gdalinfo` as follows:

```
ogrinfo -so -al PGeo:sample_pgeo
```

Where `sample_pgeo` is a name of DSN entry in the `.odbc.ini` file.

If you want to retrieve metadata for only one layer, than you would do:

```
ogrinfo -so -al PGeo:sample_pgeo <layer_name>
```

Note that you can check that your GDAL supports Personal Geodatabases by confirming that both 'PGeo' is listed when you run `ogrinfo --formats`.  More details concerning configuration and use of the Personal Geodatabase driver are provided [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html)